# Hibernate query returns same rows

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have a oracle table with no primary key defined.

Message Table
Columns are following:

```
 id - Number
 msg_number - Number
 msg_desc - Varchar2
```

I have following data

```
    1234 1 Msg1
    1234 2 Msg2
    1234 1 Msg1_3
    1234 3 Msg3
```

When i do

```
select * from myschema.message where id=1234 it returns me above four rows.
```

When i do it via Hibernate
It returns 4 in the list but they are all the same rows.

Do i need to put a PK on the table?

Here is my find method

public List find(Long id){

```
        String queryString = "from Message m  where m.id=:id ORDER BY ID";


        return (List<Message>)getSessionFactory()
             .getCurrentSession()
             .createQuery(queryString)
             .setParameter("id", id).list();            

    }
```

Comment: What did you define in the Hibernate entity as the PK?

Comment: This table has no PK. This my entity looks like

Comment: @Entity 
@Table(name = "MESSAGE", schema = "MY_SCHEMA")

Comment: Can you include `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file and show how the query looks like?

Comment: I might be wrong, but hibernate enforces that at least one column is annotated with @id; which column have you annotated as such?

Comment: Updated above with my find() method. id column is defined as @Id annotation even though it is not a PK.